# A constrained prolongement 

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a domain of $R^n$, let $\omega$ be open subset of $\Omega$ and let $\theta \in  W^{2,\infty}(\omega).$

I am wondering about the existence of a function $\tilde{\theta} \in W^{2,\infty}(\Omega)$ (eventually, under some conditions on the value of $\theta $ on $\partial \omega$) such that :

1) $ \tilde{\theta}=\theta$ on $\omega,$

2) $\Delta \tilde{\theta}=0$ on $\Omega-\omega.$

Thanks!

Comment: Which special cases have you already tried to do? What have you already tried doing? See http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask

Comment: I sudied the case $n=1,\, \Omega = (a,b)$ and $ \omega=(c,d).$ Then I complete $\theta$ on $\Omega$ by the tangent equtions $\theta'(c)(x-c)+\theta(c), $ for $a<x<c $ and $ \theta'(d)(x-d)+\theta(d),$ for $d<x<b.$

Comment: $W^{2,\infty}$-estimates in dimension $n\ge 2$ are not always true without assuming further regularity on the other terms, so dimension $1$ might not generalize so nicely. 

As regards your problem, $\tilde\theta$ may only depends on the $\theta$ and $\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial n}$ at the boundary $\partial\omega$. The values inside $\omega$ don't matter so much as long as they match with the traces I mentioned. 

Comment: If we try to extend the above idea to the case $n=2$ : for $x\in \Omega-\omega,$ we consider the normal to $\partial\omega$ at $\xi$ and passing from $x$. Then we set $ \tilde{\theta}(x)=\theta'(\xi)(x-\xi)+\theta(\xi).$


Comment: Cross-posted to MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179109/extension-with-harmonic-function

Comment: As Leonid Kovalev appears to have given a nice counter-example over MSE, I vote to close the question here.